# How to implement Callback(Kotlin) before use Kotlin lib in Android Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Can you help me integrating a lib in Android (Java)?
I have an issue in `setOnRangeListener` from Kotlin to Java.

In Java

```
custCalendar.setOnRangeSelectedListener(...?);
```

example Function In Kotlin

```
calendar_view.setOnRangeSelectedListener { startDate, endDate, startLabel, endLabel ->
    departure_date.text = startLabel
    return_date.text = endLabel
}
```

This will be called when the only a single day is selected for both SINGLE and RANGE type

```
calendar_view.setOnStartSelectedListener { startDate, label ->
    departure_date.text = label
    return_date.text = "-"
}

fun setOnStartSelectedListener(callback: (startDate: Date, label: String) -> Unit) {
    mOnStartSelectedListener = callback
}

fun setOnRangeSelectedListener(callback: (startDate: Date, endDate: Date, startLabel: String, endLabel: String) -> Unit) {
    mOnRangeSelectedListener = callback
}
```

How to implement this function?

Comment: @Hatthakorn what is the name of that library? In Java `setOnRangeSelectedListener `most likely accepts an Interface. What is the name of it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this  in java, but I cant see the name of your interface so i leave this option :

```
custCalendar.setOnRangeSelectedListener(new OnRangeSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRangeSelected(@NonNull Object1 object, @NonNull Object2 object2) {

    }
  });
```

Comment: in lib don't have a interface fun is just a fun
private var mOnRangeSelectedListener: (startDate: Date, endDate: Date, startLabel: String, endLabel: String) -> Unit =
        { _, _, _, _ -> }

fun setOnRangeSelectedListener(callback: (startDate: Date, endDate: Date, startLabel: String, endLabel: String) -> Unit) {
        mOnRangeSelectedListener = callback
    }

Answer (score 0):

i think you can call it in class java
try this code

```
 custCalendar.setOnRangeSelectedListener((startDate,label)->{
  
  // use parameters of function there

  return null
 });
```